# Hi, how to edit just a few columns and not all? on jquery and html?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I wanted only the date and value to be edited, how to fix this flaw? Just below is the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tblEditavel tbody tr').each(function(i){
        $(this).children('td').each(function(p){
            $(this).dblclick(function(){
            if($('td > input').length > 0) {
                return;
            }
                var conteudoOriginal = $(this).text();
                var novoElemento = $('<input/>', {type:'text', value: conteudoOriginal});
                    $(this).html(novoElemento.bind('blur keydown', function(e) {
                    var keyCode = e.which;
                    var conteudoNovo = $(this).val();
                    if(keyCode == 13 && conteudoNovo != '' && conteudoNovo != conteudoOriginal) {
                        var objeto = $(this);
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "alterar.php",
                        data: {
                            id: $(this).parents('tr').children().first().text(),
                            campo: $(this).parent().attr('title'),
                            valor: conteudoNovo
                        },
                            success: function(result) {
                                objeto.parent().html(conteudoNovo);
                                $('body').append(result);
                            }
                        })
                        var posicao = p + 1;
                        $(this).parent()
                                .html(conteudoNovo)
                                .parents('tr')
                                .next()
                                .children('td:nth-child('+posicao+')')
                                .trigger('dblclick');
                    
                    } 
      else if (keyCode == 27 || e.type == 'blur')
                        $(this).parent().html(conteudoOriginal);
                    
                    }));
                    $(this).children().select();
            });
        });
    });
})
```

```css
table{
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            table, td, th{
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 5px;
                
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <table id="tblEditavel">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>R$</th>
                    <th>Date pay</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>74</td>
                    <td title="Nome" class="editavel">Microsoft</td>
                    <td title="valor" class="editavel">2.350,00</td>
                    <td title="vencimento" class="editavel">10/02/2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>75</td>
                    <td title="Nome" class="editavel">Microsoft</td>
                    <td title="valor" class="editavel">2.350,00</td>
                    <td title="vencimento" class="editavel">10/03/2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>76</td>
                    <td title="Nome" class="editavel">Microsoft</td>
                    <td title="valor" class="editavel">2.350,00</td>
                    <td title="vencimento" class="editavel">10/04/2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>77</td>
                    <td title="Nome" class="editavel">Microsoft</td>
                    <td title="valor" class="editavel">2.350,00</td>
                    <td title="vencimento" class="editavel">10/05/2017</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>78</td>
                    <td title="Nome" class="editavel">Microsoft</td>
                    <td title="valor" class="editavel">2.350,00</td>
                    <td title="vencimento" class="editavel">10/06/2017</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Already tried `$('#tblEditavel tbody tr td.editavel').each(function(i)')` but it does not work.
Where I am wrong, ajax is working normal but double clicking on another column generates error, since I only want to edit two columns.

Comment: You don't need to use `.each()` when binding event handlers. Just bind to the entire collection, jQuery automatically iterates.

Comment: I couldnt understand what do you want.
Do you want to make R$ and Date pay field editable ?
Like when you click on it ?

Comment: @Nezih Yes, only these two fields and not the whole table. Thanks.

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso
I'll try to make a demo for you.
Edit: what about this ?
Check this out https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

Comment: @Barmar the code is functional and when enter enter it goes to the next line but all the td are being edited but I want to limit only the two columns pay and date

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso My comment wasn't about how to solve the problem, it was just general advice about using jQuery. The solution to the problem is in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$('#tblEditavel tbody tr td.editavel').dblclick()` works, as long as you take `class="editavel"` out of the Name `TD`s.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tblEditavel tbody tr td.editavel').dblclick(function(p) {
    if ($('td > input').length > 0) {
      return;
    }
    var conteudoOriginal = $(this).text();
    var novoElemento = $('<input/>', {
      type: 'text',
      value: conteudoOriginal
    });
    $(this).html(novoElemento.bind('blur keydown', function(e) {
      var keyCode = e.which;
      var conteudoNovo = $(this).val();
      if (keyCode == 13 && conteudoNovo != '' && conteudoNovo != conteudoOriginal) {
        var objeto = $(this);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "alterar.php",
          data: {
            id: $(this).parents('tr').children().first().text(),
            campo: $(this).parent().attr('title'),
            valor: conteudoNovo
          },
          success: function(result) {
            objeto.parent().html(conteudoNovo);
            $('body').append(result);
          }
        })
        var posicao = p + 1;
        $(this).parent()
          .html(conteudoNovo)
          .parents('tr')
          .next()
          .children('td:nth-child(' + posicao + ')')
          .trigger('dblclick');

      } else if (keyCode == 27 || e.type == 'blur')
        $(this).parent().html(conteudoOriginal);

    }));
    $(this).children().select();
  });
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblEditavel">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>R$</th>
      <th>Date pay</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>74</td>
      <td title="Nome">Microsoft</td>
      <td title="valor" class="editavel">2.350,00</td>
      <td title="vencimento" class="editavel">10/02/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>75</td>
      <td title="Nome">Microsoft</td>
      <td title="valor" class="editavel">2.350,00</td>
      <td title="vencimento" class="editavel">10/03/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>76</td>
      <td title="Nome">Microsoft</td>
      <td title="valor" class="editavel">2.350,00</td>
      <td title="vencimento" class="editavel">10/04/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>77</td>
      <td title="Nome">Microsoft</td>
      <td title="valor" class="editavel">2.350,00</td>
      <td title="vencimento" class="editavel">10/05/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>78</td>
      <td title="Nome">Microsoft</td>
      <td title="valor" class="editavel">2.350,00</td>
      <td title="vencimento" class="editavel">10/06/2017</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```